# Generate vb class from xsd. xmldsig#:SignatureType

Tags: vb.net, class, xsd

I'm trying to generate a vb.net class using the xsd tool, from a xsd file, but I receiving the following message:

schema validation warning: complext type 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignatureType

Warning: cannot generate classes because no top-level element with complex type were found.

Thanks!
Davis

Answer (score 1):

better late than never...
You have to pass 2 parameters. Your file, and the http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd reference. As XSD.exe only accepts 1 input parameter, you have to pass it .Xsd paths.

So, you have to do this:

1. Download xmldsig-core-schema.xsd schema.
2. Run this:

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vXXXX\bin\xsd.exe" 
      [path_your_folder]\your_file.xsd
      [path_to_your_folder]\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd /c /n:mi_new_class_file_name /l:VB

The new file "mi_new_class_file_name.vb" may be now into your "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vXXXX\bin" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with XSD.EXE, it would work for some simple XSDs, but anything complex - bunch of various errors and that is. What made problem worse, I am fairly amature with XSD/WSDLs. In my experience, i had several WSDLs, each imported  2 to 5 external XSD.

Here is what I did to get Classes from XSD:

-Download and install free tool [XSD2CODE](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/)

-Run in command line:

`"<PATH to Xsd2Code executable>\Xsd2Code.exe" YourXSDFile.xsd /l vb`

That generated classes for me even when XSD.EXE could not.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but using the sxd2code I get the same error: Undefined complextype 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldesig#:SignatureType' is used as a base for complex type extension.

Comment: Does your WSDL/XSD validates successfully? Maybe you have an error in there.